# Transition from 3DsMax to Blender

Tags: filmic-blender

I want to know is there a UI mode change in blender that simulates 3Dsmax UI... i am new in blender and I kind of get lost.

Comment: I think 2.92 only have Maya Preset under Edit > Preferences > Themes > Presets

Comment: @Emir thankyou I will check it up.. (but I don't use Maya)